# Please prove divergence of arithmetic mean.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

My textbook has the following proposition in it.
However, I only know how to solve the problem halfway.

**Proposition**
$a_n \to \infty (n \to \infty) \Rightarrow b_n=\frac{a_1+\dots +a_n}{n}\to \infty$

**My proof (halfway through)**
For any $K \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a number $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $n> N\Rightarrow a_n > K$ .

$b_n = \frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{n}=\frac{a_1+\dots+a_N}{n}+\frac{a_N+1+\dots+a_n}{n}$

$>\frac{M}{n}+\frac{n-N}{n}K$  $(M:=a_1+\dots+a_N)$

$=\frac{M}{n}+(1-\frac{N}{n})K$

$=K+\frac{1}{n}(M-NK)$

$=\dots$

What should I do after this?
Please tell me the rest of the proof.

Comment: Hint: With your $K$ and $N$, what can you say about $b_{2N}$?

Comment: I think we may also need to separate out an initial finite sequence which could contain negative values from a following positive infinite sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $K \in \mathbb{R}^+$ there exists a number $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$n> N_1\Rightarrow a_n > 2K.$$
Now fix $N_1$ and then for $n> N_1$,
\begin{eqnarray}
b_n &=& \frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{n}=\frac{a_1+\dots+a_{N_1}}{n}+\frac{a_{N_1+1}+\dots+a_n}{n}\\
&\ge&\frac{M}{n}+\frac{n-N_1}{n}\cdot2K \\
&=&2K+\frac{1}{n}(M-2N_1K)
\end{eqnarray}
where
$$ M:=a_1+\dots+a_{N_1}. $$
Since $M, N_1, K$ are finite numbers, there is $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$n> N_2\Rightarrow K+\frac{1}{n}(M-2N_1K)>0.$$
Define $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Then for given $K>0$ and above $N$, one has
$$ n>N\Rightarrow b_n>K. $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your proof is correct in case of $K\geq0$. I want to know generally proof. How to prove $K<0$ ?

Comment: Just reverse the inequalities for $a_n,b_n$.

Comment: I'm sorry. My explanation was inadequate. In my textbook, the definition of divergence of $a_n$ is as follows. For any $ K \in \mathbb{R} $ there exists a number $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ n> N \Rightarrow a_n > K $. Thanks to your answer, I understood in case of $K>0$ , but I also want to know in case of $K<0$. Please let me know how I can prove this.

Comment: You can do the same.